# Compilation error with adaptable function objects in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am learning how to use standard generic algorithms in c++. In the below code example I am trying to convert strings to double with the help of a custom compose function that combines two operations `(string to const char* and const char* to double)` into one.

I have written `unary_composer` as a adaptable function object.

However when i compile it, i am getting below error

> Error 2   error C2664: 'double unary_composer::operator ()(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> *)' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> *

'

```
using namespace std;

template<typename F1, typename F2>
class unary_composer : public unary_function<typename F2::argument_type, typename F1::result_type>
{
    F1 f1;
    F2 f2;

public:
unary_composer(F1 lf1, F2 lf2) : f1(lf1), f2(lf2){}

typename F1::result_type operator()(typename F2::argument_type x)
{
   return f1(f2(x));
}

};

template <typename F1, typename F2>
unary_composer<F1, F2> compose(F1 fone, F2 ftwo)
{
   return unary_composer<F1, F2>(fone, ftwo);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   const int SZ = 9;
   vector<string> vs(SZ);

   srand(time(0));

   generate(vs.begin(), vs.end(), NumGenerator()); // Generates strings with random digits ex: "12.35". NumGenerator is defined in another source file.

   vector<double> vd;

   // Transform the strings to doubles
   transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), back_inserter(vd), compose(ptr_fun(atof), mem_fn(&string::c_str)));

   copy(vd.begin(), vd.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " ")); // print to console
   cout<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When I use `mem_fun_ref` in place of `mem_fn`, it works fine. Perhaps, the error says `unary_composer's` opeartor function is expecting argument of type `const string*` but string is getting passed. but i don't know how to fix it. Where am I missing ?

PS: The example is taken from Thinking in C++ vol2 (chapt 6)

Comment: The issue is with `mem_fn::argument_type`, which is a pointer. Are you stuck with C++03, or can you use more recent versions?

Comment: OK, because `mem_fn` is C++11, but VS2010 is quite limited in C++11 support.

Comment: I added a C++11 version, which doesn't use deprecated features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)'s `argument_type` is pointer to the type, which breaks your `unary_composer` which uses it as its `own argument_type`.

Depending on the level of C++11 support in your compiler, you could change the composer to something along the lines of

```
template<typename F1, typename F2>
class unary_composer
{
    F1 f1;
    F2 f2;

public:
    unary_composer(F1 lf1, F2 lf2) : f1(lf1), f2(lf2){}

    template <typename ARG>
    auto operator()(ARG x)->decltype(f1(f2(x))
    {
        return f1(f2(x));
    }
};
```

and invoke it like this:

```
transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), back_inserter(vd),
          compose(std::atof, mem_fn(&string::c_str)));
```

See a [working example](http://ideone.com/HdHF4n).

For completeness, here's a version that does not require you to roll out any functors:

```
transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), back_inserter(vd),
         [](const std::string& s)
         {return std::stod(s);});
```

Note that `mem_fun`, `mem_fun_ref`, `unary_functor` and others are deprecated since C++11 and will most likely be removed in C++17.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to go through the documentation of decltype but I  still couldn't understand how the type of Arg is being deduced in this example.  I guess here the purpose of using decltype is to deduce return type from f1(f2(x)) but its not clear how the type of Arg is being deduced. Can you help me please ?

Comment: @cexplorer You are right about `decltype`. The trick with `operator()` is that it is also a template, and its template parameter `ARG` can be deduced from the type of the parameter passed to it.